# Reactjs: Failed Prop Types: Unable to get the values from props while posting new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-props

I'm working on a social app where a user is supposed to post screams, do likes and comments. The problem I'm facing that **I am not getting the props value when I am posting a new scream but after reloading of the page, everything is working fine.**

This is **home.js** from where I'm sending props to Scream.js:-

```
class home extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getScreams();
  }
  render() {
    const { screams, loading } = this.props.data;
    let recentScreamsMarkup = !loading ? (
      screams.map((scream) => <Scream key={scream.screamId} scream={scream} />)
    ) : (
      <ScreamSkeleton />
    );
    return (
      <Grid container spacing={10}>
        <Grid item sm={8} xs={12}>
          {recentScreamsMarkup}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
          <Profile />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

home.propTypes = {
  getScreams: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data: state.data,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getScreams })(home);
```

This is **Scream.js** which is receiving props and shows the screams on the screen:-

```
class Scream extends Component {
  render() {
    dayjs.extend(relativeTime);
    const {
      classes,
      scream: {
        body,
        createdAt,
        userImage,
        userHandle,
        screamId,
        likeCount,
        commentCount,
      },
      user: {
        authenticated,
        credentials: { handle },
      },
    } = this.props;

    const deleteButton =
      authenticated && userHandle === handle ? (
        <DeleteScream screamId={screamId} />
      ) : null;
    console.log("Image", { userImage });
    console.log("Handle", { userHandle });
    console.log("Body", { body });

    return (
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardMedia
          image={userImage}
          title="Profile image"
          className={classes.image}
        />
        <CardContent className={classes.content}>
          <Typography
            variant="h5"
            component={Link}
            to={`/users/${userHandle}`}
            color="primary"
          >
            {userHandle}
          </Typography>
          {deleteButton}
          <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
            {dayjs(createdAt).fromNow()}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body1">{body}</Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

Scream.propTypes = {
  user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  scream: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  openDialog: PropTypes.bool,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  user: state.user,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Scream));
```

This is **PostScream.js** for posting screams:-

```
class PostScream extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    body: "",
    errors: {},
  };

  UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.UI.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.UI.errors,
      });
    }
    if (!nextProps.UI.errors && !nextProps.UI.loading) {
      this.setState({
        body: "",
        open: false,
        errors: {},
      });
    }
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.props.clearErrors();
    this.setState({ open: false, errors: {} });
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.postScream({ body: this.state.body });
  };

  render() {
    const { errors } = this.state;
    const {
      classes,
      UI: { loading },
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <MyButton onClick={this.handleOpen} tip="Post a Scream!">
          <AddIcon />
        </MyButton>

        <Dialog
          open={this.state.open}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
          fullWidth
          maxWidth="sm"
        >
          <MyButton
            tip="Close"
            onClick={this.handleClose}
            tipClassName={classes.closeButton}
          >
            <CloseIcon />
          </MyButton>

          <DialogTitle> Post a new Scream </DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <TextField
                name="body"
                type="text"
                label="SCREAM!"
                multiline
                rows="3"
                placeholder="What's on your mind!"
                error={errors.body ? true : false}
                helperText={errors.body}
                className={classes.TextField}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                fullWidth
              />

              <Button
                type="submit"
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.submitButton}
                disabled={loading}
              >
                Submit
                {loading && (
                  <CircularProgress
                    size={30}
                    className={classes.progressSpinner}
                  />
                )}
              </Button>
            </form>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

PostScream.propTypes = {
  postScream: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  clearErrors: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  UI: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  UI: state.UI,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { postScream, clearErrors })(
  withStyles(styles)(PostScream)
);
```

As u can see in Scream.js I'm printing the values of props in console which I'm getting as undefined but after a reload I'm getting the values.

**Image while posting a new Scream:-**
[While Posting a new Scream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUFOl.png)

**Image After Reloading:-**
[After Reloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvKwo.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with class based components, barley have. Could you show me how you're updating it when you post your scream? **Also delete/crop your pictures!** Don't show your private data. I would highly suggest you try out functional components.

Comment: I just have a Navigation.js where there is a "+" sign button and onClick of that PostScream component will be called. And i'm showing the data for debugging purpose. I'll definitely hide it! I'll update you after changing Scream.js to a functional Component.